Fundamental Group of Square With Relations
Let $X$ be space obtained from $[0,1]\times [0,1]$ with $(0,1)\sim(1,1)$ and $(t,0)\sim (1,t/2)$ for every $t\in [0,1]$. I want to calculate $\pi_1(X)$. I am trying to find its cell-decomposition first. I use five $0$-cells, given by vertices of the square and the point $(1,1/2)$, then five $1$-cells by divide the edge $1\times [0,1]$ to two parts, and one $2$-cell. Then this square can be drawn as pentagon, and I label the edges from the bottom counterclockwise by $a,b,c,d,e$, and we glue $a$ and $b$, also the endpoints of $d$. From here I am not sure the structure of its $1$-skeleton and how to compute its fundamental group. We did not discuss this in class but I am curious about this.

Have you labelled the vertices too? And computed which are glued together? That's also necessary.

@LeeMosher no, after I label those, how can I compute the fundamental group? Assume we label that by left end vertex of $a$, counterclockwise by $A,B,C,D,E$.

This problem can be easily solved using SVK, but I suppose a detailed solution may help you.
Let us consider the following cover: $A=X\setminus\{\left(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}\right)\}$, $B=\left(\frac{1}{3}, \frac{2}{3}\right)\times\left(\frac{1}{3}, \frac{2}{3}\right)$.
We may express $\pi_1(X)$ by means of amalgamation of the groups $\pi_1(A)$, $\pi_1(B)$ along $\pi_1(A\cap B)$. Let us figure them out.
$B$ is contractible via a radial homotopy, hence $\pi_1(B)=\{1\}$;
I now claim that $A$ is homotopic to $S^1\vee S^1\vee S^1$. I do not actually need this, since we only care about its fundamental group.
Via - again - a radial retraction onto the border of the square, we obtain that $A$ is homotopic to the following graph:

where all identification are explicited. This is a graph with only $2$ vertices and $4$ distinct arcs: two of those arcs link the vertices $A$ and $B$, and the other $2$ arcs determine a loop based in $A$ and one based in $B$:

And its fundamental group is $F_3$, the free group on $3$ generators (again by a SVK argument or noting that we can contract one of the arc between $A$ and $B$ with a homotopy equivalence to obtain a wedge of circles).
Now we are left with $A\cap B$ which is clearly homeomorphic to $S^1$.\
The inclusion $A\cap B\hookrightarrow A$ induces a map on the fundamental group which is $\pi_1(A\cap B)\cong \mathbb{Z}\ni 1 \mapsto abbcd\in F_3\cong \pi_1(A)$ by simply following counterclockwise the edges of the first image.\
By the Seifert Van-Kampen theorem, we finally obtain that $\pi_1(X)=<b, ca , a^{-1}da | bbcda=1>$.

what are the meanings of triangle and square jn the diagram?

I used them just to make clear which of the edges were identified. All the edges are different except for the two with the arrow.

I see, thank you
